# FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" - URL working fine without mentioning index.php using nginx reverse proxy

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have prepared a docker environment to run certain PHP based websites using nginx reverse proxy. Things mostly work except for one glitch. The URLs return the output of `index.php` just fine without mentioning `index.php` `http://web.local/web`, however, when I do it like `http://web.local/web/index.php` or any `.php` file for that matter.

`web` container gives the following error.

> 2021/10/24 11:18:19 [error] 28#28: *3 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.224.6, server: proxy, request: "GET /web/index.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://192.168.224.4:9000", host: "web.local"

and `nginx` container gives following error.

> 192.168.224.1 - - [24/Oct/2021:11:18:19 +0000] "GET /web/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 27 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36"

I've tried to search previous posts of this `FastCGI sent in stderr` error but nothing matches my problem.

Possible issues seem to be difference in users. NGINX proxy container uses `root` whereas PHP-FPM container uses `www-data`. Below are my configuration files.

**NGINX (proxy) nginx.conf**

```
user root;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

    upstream nginx-web {
        server web:8110;
    }

    upstream nginx-portal {
        server portal:8115;
    }

    upstream nginx-api {
        server api:8120;
    }

    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name proxy;

        location /web {
            proxy_pass          http://nginx-web;
        }

        location /portal {
            proxy_pass          http://nginx-portal;
        }

        location /api {
            proxy_pass          http://nginx-api;
        }
    }
}
```

**Server block (web) default.conf**

```
server {
    listen 8110;
    root /var/www/web;
    server_name proxy;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        index index.php;
    }

    location ~ ^/.+\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass  php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include       fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - "${PROJECT_ROOT}/db:/var/lib/mysql"
      - ./conf/db/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf:ro
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - backend

  proxy:
    container_name: proxy
    image: nginx:mainline-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./conf/proxy/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8110:8110"
      - "8115:8115"
      - "8120:8120"
    depends_on:
      - web
      - portal
      - api
    networks:
      - backend

  web:
    container_name: web
    image: nginx:mainline-alpine
    volumes:
      - "${PROJECT_ROOT}/web:/var/www/web"
      - ./conf/web/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - backend

  portal:
    container_name: portal
    image: nginx:mainline-alpine
    volumes:
      - "${PROJECT_ROOT}/portal:/var/www/portal"
      - ./conf/portal/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - db
      - php
    networks:
      - backend

  api:
    container_name: api
    image: nginx:mainline-alpine
    volumes:
      - "${PROJECT_ROOT}/api:/var/www/api"
      - ./conf/api/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - backend

  php:
    container_name: php
    image: maciejslawik/php-fpm-xdebug:latest
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - "${PROJECT_ROOT}/web:/var/www/web"
      - "${PROJECT_ROOT}/portal:/var/www/portal"
      - "${PROJECT_ROOT}/api:/var/www/api"
      - ./conf/php/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini:ro
    networks:
      - backend

  composer:
    container_name: composer
    image: composer:2
    restart: "no"
    command: install
    volumes:
      - "${PROJECT_ROOT}/composer:/app"
      - ./composer/composer.json:/app/composer.json
    networks:
      - backend

  phinx:
    container_name: phinx
    image: vegbrasil/phinx:latest
    volumes:
      - "${PROJECT_ROOT}/migrations/database/migrations:/app/database/migrations"
      - "${PROJECT_ROOT}/migrations/database/seeds:/app/database/seeds"
      - ./conf/phinx/phinx.php:/app/phinx.php:ro
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: "no"
    command: "status"
    environment:
      - TESTS_PHINX_DB_ADAPTER_MYSQL_HOST=db
    networks:
      - backend

  schemaspy:
    container_name: schemaspy
    image: schemaspy/schemaspy:latest
    volumes:
      - "${PROJECT_ROOT}/schemaspy/output:/output"
      - ./conf/schemaspy/schemaspy.properties:/schemaspy.properties:ro
    restart: "no"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
```

I've tried to check the output of `return 200 $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` and it returns correct values.

The default `PHP-FPM` user `www-data` doesn't have permission to `chmod` or `chcon` any file or directory.

**$_SERVER vardump**

```
array (size=53)
  'PHP_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS' => string '--enable-fpm --with-fpm-user=www-data --with-fpm-group=www-data --disable-cgi' (length=77)
  'HOSTNAME' => string '4b4c2f5dcdb7' (length=12)
  'PHP_INI_DIR' => string '/usr/local/etc/php' (length=18)
  'HOME' => string '/var/www' (length=8)
  'PHP_LDFLAGS' => string '-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=both -pie' (length=34)
  'PHP_CFLAGS' => string '-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' (length=83)
  'PHP_MD5' => string '' (length=0)
  'PHP_VERSION' => string '7.4.0' (length=5)
  'GPG_KEYS' => string '42670A7FE4D0441C8E4632349E4FDC074A4EF02D 5A52880781F755608BF815FC910DEB46F53EA312' (length=81)
  'PHP_CPPFLAGS' => string '-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' (length=83)
  'PHP_ASC_URL' => string 'https://www.php.net/get/php-7.4.0.tar.xz.asc/from/this/mirror' (length=61)
  'PHP_URL' => string 'https://www.php.net/get/php-7.4.0.tar.xz/from/this/mirror' (length=57)
  'PATH' => string '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin' (length=60)
  'PHPIZE_DEPS' => string 'autoconf         dpkg-dev        file        g++         gcc         libc-dev        make        pkg-config      re2c' (length=76)
  'PWD' => string '/var/www/html' (length=13)
  'PHP_SHA256' => string '9bb751b20e5d6cc1ea9b1ebf23ef2d5f07f99b2d9cc417bf1d70c04f8b20ec42' (length=64)
  'USER' => string 'www-data' (length=8)
  'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => string 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ur;q=0.8' (length=23)
  'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => string 'gzip, deflate' (length=13)
  'HTTP_ACCEPT' => string 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' (length=135)
  'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => string 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36' (length=114)
  'HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS' => string '1' (length=1)
  'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL' => string 'max-age=0' (length=9)
  'HTTP_CONNECTION' => string 'close' (length=5)
  'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST' => string 'proxy' (length=5)
  'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' => string '192.168.224.1' (length=13)
  'HTTP_X_REAL_IP' => string '192.168.224.1' (length=13)
  'HTTP_HOST' => string 'web.local' (length=9)
  'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => string '/var/www/web/index.php' (length=22)
  'REDIRECT_STATUS' => string '200' (length=3)
  'SERVER_NAME' => string 'proxy' (length=5)
  'SERVER_PORT' => string '8110' (length=4)
  'SERVER_ADDR' => string '192.168.224.7' (length=13)
  'REMOTE_PORT' => string '54314' (length=5)
  'REMOTE_ADDR' => string '192.168.224.6' (length=13)
  'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => string 'nginx/1.21.3' (length=12)
  'GATEWAY_INTERFACE' => string 'CGI/1.1' (length=7)
  'REQUEST_SCHEME' => string 'http' (length=4)
  'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => string 'HTTP/1.0' (length=8)
  'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => string '/var/www/web' (length=12)
  'DOCUMENT_URI' => string '/index.php' (length=10)
  'REQUEST_URI' => string '/web/' (length=5)
  'SCRIPT_NAME' => string '/index.php' (length=10)
  'CONTENT_LENGTH' => string '' (length=0)
  'CONTENT_TYPE' => string '' (length=0)
  'REQUEST_METHOD' => string 'GET' (length=3)
  'QUERY_STRING' => string '' (length=0)
  'FCGI_ROLE' => string 'RESPONDER' (length=9)
  'PHP_SELF' => string '/index.php' (length=10)
  'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT' => float 1635101620.5358
  'REQUEST_TIME' => int 1635101620
  'argv' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'argc' => int 0
```

**Update:** I've changed the server > location block for php as below.

```
    location ~ ^/.+\.php(/|$) {
        return 200 $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass  php:9000;
#       fastcgi_index index.php;
        include       fastcgi_params;
#        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/web/help.php;
    }
```

**Result:** Even though I open the URL `http://web.local/web/help.php`, it downloads a file with content `/var/www/web/index.php`. With hardcoded `SCRIPT_FILENAME` it shows me the output of correct file i.e. `help.php` so doesn't look like a permission issue as I had felt earlier. I notice that `fastcgi_index` is also irrelevant.

**Question:** Where is the value of `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name` coming from?

Comment: Rebooting the PHP-FPM service usually solves these issues for me.